# Progressive Nested Radicals

Tags: number-theory, nested-radicals

If P is defined as $$P = 2\sqrt[2]{2\sqrt[3]{2\sqrt[4]{2\sqrt[5]{2...}}}}$$ And if $$P = \frac {A^e}{B}$$ for positive integers A and B, what is A and B?

Answer (score 2):

Hint: 
$$P = 2\sqrt[2]{2\sqrt[3]{2\sqrt[4]{2\sqrt[5]{2...}}}}=2^1\cdot 2^{\frac {1}{2!}}\cdot 2^{\frac{1}{3!}}\cdots=2^{1+\frac{1}{2!}+\frac{1}{3!}+\cdots}$$